# How would a humanoid need to change to sleep upside-down?

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, sleep

Related: [What parts of the human body would be negatively affected by sleeping upside down?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/116105/what-parts-of-the-human-body-would-be-negatively-affected-by-sleeping-upside-dow)

I have a character (a regular human in structure) who, for his own reasons, decides to act bat-like and sleep hanging upside-down.

Handwave the feet/attachment issue.

How would the body need to change for a person to sleep upside-down, safely, for approximately 8 hours every night?

As pointed out in the answers to the linked question above, the biggest issue seems to be the circulatory system and making that work without killing the character, but any changes that need to be made to the character's body are also welcome.

Answer (score 3):

- The upper body blood vessels should develop the same valves present in the lower body ones, preventing back flow of blood under gravity.
- The blood vessel should be able to actively compensate different position with respect to heart.
- the body should get shorter to reduce the pressure differential between top and bottom (2 meters difference accounts for 1/5 of a bar between ead and toe)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no doctor(or biologist) so I might be wrong but according to [BatWorlds](https://www.batworlds.com/bat-anatomy/)

> Bats have one way valves in their arteries so prevent the blood from flowing backwards. This is why they are able to hang upside down with the blood rushing to their heads.

Maybe doing something like that and moving the heart lower into the ribs so blood can flow into the legs easer would help.